# Optimising MySQL tables after importing

Tags: php, mysql, optimization

I have an application that requires the importing of data into MySQL tables every night. There are around 5 tables that get truncated and a PHP script processes a CSV file and inserts the data one by one. These tables hold approx 20,000 rows each.

I would like to add some indexes to columns to speed up my queries a little. However, will I have to perform some other MySQL functions to rebuild the indexes after truncating and importing the data?

Any other tips to improve performance would also be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It should not be needed to rebuild any indexes, as they are automatically maintained...

Comment: Hi ryrobbo, i am newbie, i would really like to find a solution for this. But i did not understand the part your saying. Can you please explain me 

"I would like to add some indexes to columns" this part. Pardon me! please explain me this part.  And i would really wanted to find a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Truncation will not affect indexes or any other schema, it just empties a table, so you need only add indexes once. From the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/truncate-table.html):

> Logically, TRUNCATE TABLE is similar to a DELETE statement that deletes all rows, or a sequence of DROP TABLE and CREATE TABLE statements.